# Languages w/out dependent clauses

Tags: linguistic-universals, universal-grammar, complex-sentences

Is there a language w/out dependent clauses, i.e. one in which you couldn't say e.g. "*I know **that*** x is here" w/ a *clause*, where the main clause is in italic and dependent in bold (and *that* overlaps, because you may analyze it as belonging to this or that). I suppose the lack of dependent clauses might be possible *if* a language would exclusively use a different constituent (i.e. not a sentence or clause) to convey the same meaning. Or maybe you lack so complex syntax in some pidgins (which would be unlikely to generalize to full-blown natural languages)

NOTE: The original question was about "relative clauses", which seems to be a proper subset of [dependent clauses](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/31624/13996) that I intended it to be about

Comment: Yes, relative clauses are a (large, but proper) subset of subordinate or dependent clauses (those two terms are identical).  And there is a debate raging now in syntactic circles (well, some of them) about whether  Pirahã has any subordinate clauses at all, or not. Most linguists these days don't really care much; languages vary a **lot**, after all.

Answer (score 2):

It seems [Pirahã may qualify](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4774923/) (my stress):

> Since *we do not find unambiguous relative clauses in the corpus*, we
>   cannot use them to conclude that Pirahã has recursive embedding.

As Pirahã isn't a pidgin, this could be taken as a tentative evidence that such full-blown languages may exist

PS.

> ...the lack of relative clauses might be possible if a language would
>   exclusively use a different constituent (i.e. not a sentence or
>   clause) to convey the same meaning.

It might be also possible if you were always compelled to use a separate sentence, e.g. "*I know something. It is that x is here.*" Maybe this is the case in Pirahã

EDIT: If "relative clause" is not the same as "dependent clause", as suggested by @amegnusen, my answer explodes (assuming the authors of [1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4774923/) make the distinction, which is not clear)

Answer (score 1):

There are many kinds of dependent clause. The example you provided is a content clause and not a relative clause.

In Riffian, depending on the dependent clause used, this one can be introduced by a subordinator or not. There is a subordinator "i" for the relative clauses. But nothing is used for the content clauses.

Comment: I see. We're probably using different terminology. This seems to be my fault, as I meant a catch-all term like [dependent clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause) when I said "relative clause". As for Riffian, since it has both relative and content clauses, it clearly has dependent clauses